# Select Some of Two columns based on another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**Joined_courses_table**

```
---------------------------------------
id      course1_id   course2_id
---------------------------------------
1           33           3
2           2            1

---------------------------------------
```

**Results_table**

```
---------------------------------------
course_id    value
---------------------------------------
33             50
3              40
2              70
1              130
---------------------------------------
```

Problem -> I want the Values Sum from results_table for each two pairs in the Joined_courses_table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  id, course1_id, course2_id, 
  results1.value + results2.value AS values_sum
FROM
  Joined_courses_table
  JOIN Results_table results1 ON (course1_id = results1.course_id)
  JOIN Results_table results2 ON (course2_id = results2.course_id)
```

The query should perform well if you have a `PRIMARY KEY` on `Results_table.course_id`.